# How to make a menu like the Sculpt Brush/MatCap menu with Python?

Tags: scripting

I'd like to make a menu with images like the sculpt brush menu and MatCap menu in Blender with Python. Can anybody walk me through it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matcap menu is written in C, so you can't define your own menu in Python for showing arbitrary images.

To see where the menu is called...

- Open the text editor view.
- Right click on the menu, select `Edit Source`
- the line of python script that shows the matcap is displayed.

See that this is a `template` which means its a preset UI.